# Slack Block-kit Multi_users_select Remove defaults app

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api, slack-block-kit

I implemented a slack bot with um field of type input(multi_users_select). I would like to remove defaults apps from the list select?

```js
{
            type: 'input',
            element: {
                type: 'multi_users_select',
                action_id: input.actionId,
                initial_users: input.initial_users,
            },
            label: {
                type: 'plain_text',
                text: input.text,
                emoji: input.emoji,
            },
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67937080/how-to-removing-the-apps-in-input-multi-users-select-from-slack

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `type: 'multi_users_select'` use `"type": "multi_conversations_select"` with **filter** as shown below to get only users in your workspace.
You can copy and paste the below code in block-kit builder to test on your own.
https://app.slack.com/block-kit-builder/

```
{
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Blocker-Bot"
    },
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit"
    },
    "type": "modal",
    "callback_id": "custom_time_select",
    "private_metadata": "private-data",
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Test block with multi conversations select"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "multi_conversations_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select conversations",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "filter": {
                    "include": [
                        "im"
                    ],
                    "exclude_bot_users": true
                },
                "action_id": "multi_conversations_select-action"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update 05-Jul-21**

Included various other types of select users without bots/apps

```
{
    "type": "modal",
    "title": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "My App",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "submit": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Submit",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "close": {
        "type": "plain_text",
        "text": "Cancel",
        "emoji": true
    },
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Conversations type Select user"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "conversations_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select a user",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "filter": {
                    "include": [
                        "im"
                    ],
                    "exclude_bot_users": true
                },
                "action_id": "users_select-action"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": "Multi Conversations type Select users"
            },
            "accessory": {
                "type": "multi_conversations_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select conversations",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "filter": {
                    "include": [
                        "im"
                    ],
                    "exclude_bot_users": true
                },
                "action_id": "multi_conversations_select-action"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "input",
            "element": {
                "type": "multi_conversations_select",
                "placeholder": {
                    "type": "plain_text",
                    "text": "Select users",
                    "emoji": true
                },
                "filter": {
                    "include": [
                        "im"
                    ],
                    "exclude_bot_users": true
                },
                "action_id": "multi_users_select-action"
            },
            "label": {
                "type": "plain_text",
                "text": "Input type Select users",
                "emoji": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: jeevu94 very very thanks your comment . would align the select there to the left, leaving it close to the text ?

Comment: @user2915350 i didn't get that. But i've updated answers with various other types to select users without apps/bots. See if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, filtering is available for conversations select menu or conversations multi select menu.
https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/composition-objects#filter_conversations

May be you can write to feedback@slack.com and they can log it for future releases.

Comment: Suyash Gaur very thank you for your comment. Both objects: conversations select menu and conversations multi select menu, only get users after conversation in channel, correct?

Comment: Can you elaborate `only get users after conversation in channel`, it is not clear to me.
Meanwhile you can get further information here: https://api.slack.com/reference/block-kit/block-elements#multi_select